# Transform function usage (Lambda Issue)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to use the transform function in Spark SQl

```
df2 = spark.sql("select transform(array(1, 2 ,3), (x,y,z) ->x+y+z ) from  A group by company_id").show(truncate=False)
```

Expected output:

```
[1,2,6]  (6 since 3+2+1)
```

Error:

AnalysisException: The number of lambda function arguments '3' does not match the number of arguments expected by the higher-order function '1'.; line 1 pos 33

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL transform functions needs as second parameter a lambda function with 1 or 2 parameters, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform. You lambda function has 3 parameters (x,y,z). Thats what the error says.

On the other side i guess you dont use the transform function in the purpose it was built for. Transform executes a transformation on every entry of an array, e.g. "x -> x + 1". It can not unapply an array into its elements and produce a sum. To create a sum use aggregate, e.g. `aggregate(array(1, 2, 3), 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x)`